# Code Signing Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I wrote an apple watch app for my iOS app. Watch, Watch Extension and iOS app have different bundleID. I wanted to send my app to testers via fabric however I could not archive my app because of code signing issues. I could not solve the problem.

```
***Watch has conflicting provisioning settings. ***Watch is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'WatchKit App' in SDK 'watchOS 3.0'
```

Are there any documents that clearly explains how the code signing works? How should I solve signing problem?

Comment: try switching to manual from automatic

Comment: switching from auto to manual and back again also can help...

Comment: @CryingHippo please post this as an answer

Answer (score 4):

To fix this I went into each of the failing targets and selected the 'General' tab, then untick and reticked 'Automatically manage signing'.

I then reselected the correct Team and everything worked. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Great answer. I tried many approaches but no luck. Finally applied the solution provided above and it works like charm.  Thanks @Charlie Seligman